# what is the technical difference between these declarations?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, string-literals

```
  char amessage[] = "now is the time"; /* an array */
  char *pmessage = "now is the time"; /* a pointer */
```

Comment: Try `amessage = pmessage` v.s. `pmessage = amessage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`amessage` is of type `char[16]`.  It is an array.  The elements of the array contain the sixteen characters from the string literal.

`pmessage` is of type `char*`.  It is a pointer.  It points to a (non-modifiable) array containing the sixteen characters from the string literal.  (You should avoid using a `char*` to point to a string literal; doing so is evil.  You should always use a `const char*` wherever possible when referring to string literals.)

Comment: To clarify the second, the string literal itself is immutable, but the type of `pmessage` lies and says its mutable, do to a (terrible) special-case conversion.

Comment: @GMan:  It's technically not special-cased in C, since the literal is of type `char[N]` not `const char[N]` like in C++.  I agree that it is evil to use a `char*` to refer to a string literal though.

Comment: Oh, there shines my ignorance again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to James McNellis's answer, `amessage` is one thing -- an array of 16 characters on the stack that happens to contain the string "now is the time" (because they are copied there when `amessage` is created).  You can change what it contains.

On the other hand, `pmessage` is two things -- a string literal (which is stored in a non-writable portion of memory), and a pointer.  You can't change the contents of the string literal, but you can change what the pointer points to, and make it point at a different string.  And you can use the string literal as a target of other pointers.

(In some sense, this is not entirely true -- `amessage` also involves a string literal, as it's where the contents are copied from when it's created.  But you can't do anything *else* with that string literal afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using GCC, turn on -Wwrite-strings.  fixed strings are of type const char[length_of_string], and the conversion to a char * will elicit a warning [needs to be const].

The first assignment is a character array assignment, whereas the second assignment is a pointer-based assignment (and the resulting string is held as a fixed string)

The first assignment is acceptable as-is, whereas the second one requires a const qualifier.

In the first assignment, changing a point is acceptable (e.g. amessage[3] = 'q').  in the second assignment, changing a point is unacceptable (since the string is const ) -- you should get a bus error

Answer (score 0):

```
char amessage[] = "now is the time"; /* an array */
char *pmessage = "now is the time"; /* a pointer */
```

In C the thing to the left of '=' is termed an 'lvalue'.  The type is defined solely by the 'lvalue'.   So 'amessage' is a char array.   'pmessage' is a pointer to a char.

In C more goes on in relation to what is equivalent between array type & 'char *' accesses, and also what is not.

As declared 'pmessage' is a modifiable 'lvalue' - 'amessage' is not modifiable.  Hence the advise to declare 'pmessage' as const as really it should not be modifiable also.

E.g.

```
const char* const pmessage = "...";
```

In terms of memory access 'amessage' results in a direct access, whereas 'pmessage' requires a dereference.

Note:  the C compiler only permits initialisation of 'char *' at compile time via a string literal.

E.g. If you had

```
1. {
2.     int j = 1;
3.     int *k = &j;
4.     int *i = 1;
5. }
```

Line 4 makes no sense & would be illegal.

Highly recommend Peter Van Linden's 'Deep C Secrets' which he has a whole chapter about C arrays & pointers.

Comment: `amessage` is indeed a non-modifiable lvalue because it is an array.  This means, effectively, that the named `amessage` is not assignable; it does not mean that the elements of the array are not assignable (they are assignable).  `pmessage` is indeed a modifiable lvalue (it's a pointer).  This means that you can change the pointer to point at a different object.  Declaring it as a `const char*` does not make it a non-modifiable lvalue:  it would make it a modifiable lvalue that points to a `const char`.

Comment: Yes. Amended example.  Just trying to help ... :-)